# How can I define a plpgsql function that accepts a parameter of a type that is not schema qualified and is not yet created

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

My database is structured with a schema per application user. In each schema there is an identical table named "entries" with the exact same DDL. I also have a common schema that hosts some functions that operate on those "entries" tables, and during execution the search path defines which schema's entries table the function operates on. I had a problem defining those functions before i create any user schema because they reference the non yet created tables in the user schemata. That problem was solved using `set check_function_bodies = off;` But now I have a similar problem with a function that references those tables as an inout parameter. I cannot create that function because a parameter that it accepts is of type "entries" and I get an error of "type entries does not exist". `set check_function_bodies = off` does not solve this problem. Is there a way to solve this problem?
The function signature is

```
create or replace function common.reconcile_user_entry(inout e entries) returns void
```

I really dont want to define this function in each user schema as it will always be the same, and i dont want to have to recompile it in every schema when I need to make a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going with inheritance I ended up solving it by circumventing the problem like this:

Instead of defining the function signature as

```
create or replace function common.reconcile_user_entry(inout e entries) returns void
```

I defined it as

```
create or replace function common.reconcile_user_entry(inout r record) returns void
```

and in the function code I declare a variable `e entries;` and then assign the record into the variable:

```
declare 
 e entries;
begin
 select into e r.*
...
```

Regarding the inheritance solution, it works, but I found the above solution much simpler.
I know there must be caveats and hidden problems with my solution, if someone can point, please do.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) for that.

Define a table `common.entries` just like all other `entries` tables and change the other `entries` tables to inherit from it:

```
ALTER TABLE schema1.entries INHERIT common.entries;
```

Then define the function to have `common.entries` as parameter or return type, and you can use it with any of the inherited tables.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use table inheritance.

You would have to create a "parent" table in common schema for every table you have in users schema. Then inherit users tables from them. Use "parent" table names when defining function parameters. See example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent(id integer);

CREATE TABLE child() INHERITS (parent);
INSERT INTO child(id) VALUES (1);

CREATE FUNCTION get_id(IN prm_row parent) RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
  SELECT prm_row.id;
$$;

SELECT get_id((SELECT (child) FROM child WHERE id = 1));
```

Note, that parent table will containt the records from all the child tables, so you should use permission to prevent users accessing the parent tables.